# How to get API sessions from database table

Tags: api, soap, magento-1.9, soap-client

How do I get the session ID's etc from the table 'api/session'?

I want to get an active session of a user, and return it.

I've got this to work:

But it seems very dangerous / bad practice:

```
$userId = $user->getId();

$array = [];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM api_session WHERE user_id='$userId'";
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
 foreach ($connection->fetchAll($sql) as $arr_row) {
    $array[] = $arr_row['sessid'];
 }

 return print_r($array,true);
```